# Opening a popbox when clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

The [PopBox](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/textarea-popup) plugin is useful for having a text area pop up in its own window when you click within a text area. However, I want a PopBox to appear when the user clicks a button, rather than within a text area. Is there a way to modify the PopBox functionality for this?

**tl;dr**: I want the PopBox to pop when a function is called rather than when clicking inside a text area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [popBox source](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.popBox1.3.0_0.zip), you'll see that when popBox is applied to an element (via `$('#yourElement')).popBox()`, there is a `focus` event bound to it:

```
obj.focus(function () { $(this).next(".popBox-holder").show(); var
    popBoxContainer = $(this).next().next(".popBox-container");  
    // ...edited for brevity...
});
```

Attach a click event to your button and, within that, trigger the popBox by triggering the above mentioned `focus` event:

```
// Attach a click event handler to your button
$('#yourButton').click(function(){
    // Trigger the "focus" event on the popBox element
    $('#yourElement').triggerHandler('focus');
});
```

[See a working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/URKGn/)

Obviously, you can modify this to fit your needs - e.g. hiding the initial `textarea` or `input` if you don't want it displayed.

Comment: @Briz: You're welcome - I'm glad it helped! You might also be interested in checking out the jQuery docs for the [`triggerHandler()`](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/) method, used in my example.